# How can I check the real, actual and swap percentages displayed in xymon on my linux machine?

Tags: linux

I would like to check the actual memory usage on the box.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic and easiest way is the `free` command:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G       8.3G        22G       327M       337M       4.7G
-/+ buffers/cache:       3.3G        28G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

For more information look at the `free` manpage: `man free`.